# SQL Server Reporting server doesn't connect : SQL Server 2019 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sccm, sql-server-2019

I installed SQL Server 2019 Enterprise edition (with custom instance name, not default one) with CU8 followed by SQL Server Reporting Services. But when I am trying to connect to the SQL Server Reporting Server in SQL Server Management Studio, it shows default instance name i.e. `SSRS` and it doesn't connect.

However, I am able to connect to the database engine server.

For the same reason I am not able to install Reporting Services Role in my primary site server as Reporting server instance name doesn't get populated. However I am not facing this issue in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise as SQL Server Reporting Services .exe file doesn't come as a separate file in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise and it is installed with SQL Server itself.

Comment: Are you sure you need to connect to SSRS in Management Studio?

Comment: Not needed. But I need to install Reporting services role in PSS (primary site server) and reporting service instance name is not getting populated while installing. That's why I tried to connect SSRS in management studio to check if it's connecting or not.